# is my sql query prone to sql injection or other attacks

Tags: sql, playframework, sql-injection

I was using some sql statements in views in a web app developed using playframework.I have the following java function

```
public static void search(String word){
   String trimword = word.trim();
   String pattern = "%"+trimword+"%";
   String query="select distinct item from Item item where item.name like :pattern";
   List<Item> items = Item.find(query).bind("pattern", pattern).fetch();
   ...
}
```

The 'word' is a string entered by user through a text input field in a web page form..Can the above be misused by an evil person to do nasty things to my db?I tried various combinations of user input like `'SomeItem or '1'='1'` etc but nothing unexpected happened..But my knowledge of sql is minimal ..If anyone can point out any vulnerabilities in this and suggest improvements/safeguards ,it would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.bind("pattern", pattern)` prevents SQL Injection attacks.  Thus your query is not prone to an SQL Injection attack.

Also, your code appending the `%` values is similar to a user entering the `%`. The `bind()` method will handle both the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is not prone to sql injection. As a general rule use bind variables on everything but table names and column names, which you can't use bind variables for.

So, vunerable

```
select distinct item from item where name like '&pattern'
```

impossible,

```
select distinct item from :item where name like = 'buggy'
```

okay

```
select distinct item from item where name like :pattern
```

**EDIT** @JNK, you'll have to assume that I've coded the oracle connections correctly as execute() runs to about 80 lines.

```
>>> import oracle
>>> db = oracle.OracleConnection('schema/pw@server')
>>> db.connect()
>>> SQL = """ select 1 from feed_logs where file_id = :file_id"""
>>> bind_vars = { 'file_id' : '1; delete from feed_logs'}
>>> db.DBCursor.execute(SQL, bind_vars=bind_vars)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data type dict
>>>
```

Comment: What if a user entered `1; DELETE FROM Users --`?

Comment: @JNK In the 3rd query, `Item.find(query).bind("pattern", pattern).fetch();` would need to be called.  The `bind()` method would handle escaping and preventing SQL injection.